# Is it possible to set the default property of a Qt widget?

Tags: qt, pyside

This is my first time creating a GUI using Qt.
In an application where there are a lot of Group Boxes, I would like to have them all have the "flat" property enabled.
Is there a way to change the default value of every widget of the same type?

I know it would be possible to achieve the same thing by creating a new class, based on the `QGroupBox` widget, but my goal is to actually do it with the least amount of coding possible.

Comment: You can set their properties from Qt Designer. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I can set their properties in Qt Designer, but it still changes the value of each widget, but it will still create a line of code for every existing widget. I would prefer a single line of code overwriting the default value of every widget...

Comment: Then you must subclass QGroupBox. No way to avoid it. That, or you should just change their value, @pnezis's code would do fine for that, even though it doesn't actually change the "default" value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ code follows. Should be straight forward to port in Python.

After setting up the ui of your widget do the following.

```
QList<QGroupBox *> groupboxes = this->findChildren<QGroupBox *>();
for (int i=0; i<groupboxes.count(); i++)
    groupboxes[i]->setFlat(true);
```

Comment: This seems to be what I'm looking for! Althought, I'm not fluent in C++, I'd have a hard time translating it. If someone can come up with a python translation (including myself), I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Found it! Python code is `list = self.findChildren(QtGui.QGroupBox); for item in list: item.setFlat(True)`